# Finding the toolbar of a modal NavigationPage in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, toolbar

My intention is to get a handle to the toolbar in Android native (on a xamarin forms Project). This, in order to be able to do some custom painting (a badge) on an Icon.

So... I have an Android native method doing this

```
var toolbar = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.FindViewById(Resource.Id.toolbar) as Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
```

It works fine, as long as it's the toolbar of my main page I'm after. It also works fine if I, from my main page do something like

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new NySecondPage());
```

Then it will find the correct toolbar for the second page.

My problem comes when I push a Modal page, with a toolbar, like this

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new NySecondPage()));
```

Now, if the native Android code is called, the toolbar returned is STILL the one from my main page. (Not the one currently showing on screen).

So, my question: Is there a way to find the toolbar of a modal pushed navigationpage?

Comment: Have you tried using `Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NySecondPage())` ?

Comment: Yes, but if not wrapping it insida an NavigationPage, the new page will not have a toolbar. But anyway… The toolbar returned is still the toolbar from my MainPage. 

I've read that Xamarin Forms uses only one Activity… But how to get grab of the native toolbar of a second NavigationPage…?